# Почему появляется строка с id #7?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";
$a = mysql_query($id);
echo $a;
```

У меня тут, например, id=3, а по этому коду на экране появляется вот эта строка - Resource id #7, почему?

Comment: Люблю такие заголовки у вопросов, начинаешь верить в чудо и мистику - появляется строка с id #7... О эта загадочная строка, ее появление необьяснимо, почему именно 7? Что значит эта волшебная цифра? И главное - откуда она появилась и зачем? ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну потому, что `mysql_query` возвращает не данные, а идентификатор ресурса, для того, что бы получить данные, используйте, к примеру

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf( $row[0]);  
}
```

Comment: спасибо уже работает

Comment: так прими ответ, чтобы отметился как отвеченный